# Convert video colors to red and cyan with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video

Displays red and cyan colors as 3d video. I have seen 3d videos on youtube transform their display colors to cyan and red. But here is 3d format. Is there any way to turn a video in 2d format but with red and cyan colors like 3d video
Below is an example. I look forward to enlightenment. with ffmpeg I see something's wrong.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could perhaps offset the colours, but it won't make it 3D. For 3D you need two cameras, like a pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Please always consult FFmpeg documentation, specifically stereo3d filter. It have anaglyph red-cyan modes.

For filter to work correctly you will need already video that have both views, left and right.

If you do not have video with left and right view you can not use stereo3d filter. And you could only produce fake effect (in a sense fake depth when viewing with anaglyph glasses) with chromashift filter.